# Cannot download file using wget

Tags: 14.04, server, wget, url

So i am reading *The Official Ubuntu Server Book* and i just got to the part where i make a pxe boot server. Everything looks good till i am supposed to download some files using wget. The url i entered is

http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/percise/main/installer-i386/current/images/netboot/netboot.tar.gz

i get a 404 error.
Okay..

i then go to google chrome and manually go through the folder structure and download the netboot.tar.gz file and then copy the url...
here is the url.

http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise/main/installer-i386/current/images/netboot/netboot.tar.gz

As you can see the url is identical. I even opened notepad and copy and pasted them one over the other to compare letter by letter, again both are the same yet the second link works. I am so stumped, this is probably an easy fix and im just not seeing it.

Any help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You write an error http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/**percise**/main/installer-i386/current/images/netboot/netboot.tar.gz

it would be correct http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/**precise**/main/installer-i386/current/images/netboot/netboot.tar.gz

Answer (score 0):

In your wget request you have `.../percise/...` and not `.../precise/...`. That is what causes the error.

Comment: You are welcome, that happens the best :D

Answer (score 0):

Here is you first link:

```
http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/percise/main/installer-i386/current/images/netboot/netboot.tar.gz
```

Here is your second link:

```
http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise/main/installer-i386/current/images/netboot/netboot.tar.gz
```

Comparing the two links:

[image: 1]

You can see that the typo lies in the link itself.

It should be:

"p**re**cise"

instead of

"p**er**cise"

Comment: You got it, thank you!  I cant believe i didn't see that... i literally read over those 2 lines 10 times! Guess thats what i get for staying up late!